# Ubuntu 20.04 Zpool fails to import at startup

Tags: 20.04, zfs

1. I have read through dozens of forums and blogs already.
2. My server was acting up so I backuped most things and went with a fresh install. I wanted to migrate most of my apps to docker anyways.
3. All I am trying to get is my zpool to mount at boot but it keeps failing at "zpool-import-cache" service. I erased the cache file made a new one. Deleted the cache file and try "zpool-import-scan" which also failed.
4. This is the old pool from the only thing new is the OS install.
5. I can manually add with "zpool import -a| zpool import "pool"" I can also restart the service and get it to import the pool with "systemctl restart zpool-import-cache". So zpool-import-cache.service only fails on start up not active.
6. None of this makes sense. I reboot and the enter the terminal immediately and the service restarts no problem.
7. The error in the system status comes back "cannot import "my pool" no such data/pool exist", but then I am able to import from terminal

None of that makes sense to me.

The zpool consists of 2 vdevs of 12 drives each in raidz2.

1 drive is dead and waiting for a back up but it was booting every time and loading on the old OS.

Comment: There is very little to go on here. Please provide some output from the relevant logs and services, e.g. `systemctl status zfs-import-cache.service` and `systemctl status zfs-mount.service`. Also, this is not an emergency hotline, if you need professional help in a hurry, consider a professional service.

Comment: The longs don't offer more than what I posted. That is what is frustrating.

Just Pool doesn't exist. But it does when I manually enter it.

Comment: I added "ExecStartPre=- /sbin/modprobe zfs" and ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/sleep 10" to the zfs-import-cache/service file and the pool now imports. 

Question is why isn't the import file waiting longer?

My set up is considerably small that major servers.

Comment: Please, add your solution as an answer to this question. This is perfectly acceptable, and actually encouraged.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I needed to `sudo zfs set mountpoint=/mnt/PoolName PoolName` so that it would automatically mount on startup.

[Oracle: Managing ZFS Mount Points](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gaynd/index.html)

> When you change the mountpoint property from legacy or none to a specific path, ZFS automatically mounts the file system.